# Display barcode number below barcode image

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, barcode

I'm using [Zen Barcode Rendering Framework](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Zen.Barcode.Rendering.Framework/) to genarate Barcode in my MVC application. But my problem is after barcode was generated it didn't show barcode number under the barcode image. I need to add that barcode number under it.

Here is my code:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(string barcode)
{   
    BarcodeSymbology symbology = BarcodeSymbology.Code39C;
    BarcodeDraw drawObject = BarcodeDrawFactory.GetSymbology(symbology);

    var metrics = drawObject.GetDefaultMetrics(60);
    metrics.Scale = 1;

    var barcodeImage = drawObject.Draw(barcode, metrics);

    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        barcodeImage.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
        byte[] imageBytes = ms.ToArray();

        ViewBag.BarcodeImage = "data:image/png;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
    }
    return View();
}
```

Can any one suggest a solution for this?

Comment: If you have barcode number then you can send it to view using ViewBag and display in the view under the image.

Comment: I need to add it to image.

Comment: So you want the number to be part of the image, not as text below the image?

Comment: Sounds like a feature request. I'd start by opening an issue requesting that in the library's [github repo](https://github.com/dementeddevil/BarcodeRenderingFramework).